# OC 2.x SEO URLs incompatible with Product QuickView

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I am using Opencart 2.1.0.2 version and have enabled SEO URL from Store setting as below:

[image]

Now, My Product URL is will become

```
http://example.com/category/product-name-1
```

where `product-name-1` is filled in space highlighted below

[image]

In Controller of `category.php` actual product URL is build like

```
'href' => $this->url->link('product/product', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . 
 '&product_id=' . $result['product_id'] . $url),
```

Now, for **QuickView** i have made another parameter like

```
'quick' => $this->url->link('product/quickview', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . 
 '&product_id=' . $result['product_id'])
```

Only difference here is that `QuickView` points to another controller named `QuickView` and Product URL points to `ProductDetail` controller.

In both the cases my URL for `href` and `quick` looks like ditto same

```
http://example.com/category/product-name-1
```

With this, my `quickview.tpl` file is not loaded.

> **Issue: As i am getting same URL on both then even clicking on QuickView Button opens full product detail in the modal window results into ugly presentation.**

However, if i am disabling SEO Setting from store then my URLs are like

Actual Product URL

- http://example.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=43

QuickView URL

- http://example.com/index.php?route=product/quickview&product_id=43

With this, my `quickview.tpl` file is loaded.